# pKb of a strong acid?

Tags: acid-base, ph

What does the pKb (or $K_b$) of a strong acid mean?

For instance [this link](https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/General_Chemistry/Map%3A_A_Molecular_Approach_(Tro)/16%3A_Acids_and_Bases/16.04%3A_Acid_Strength_and_the_Acid_Dissociation_Constant_(Ka)) reports the Kb of HI, an extremely strong acid. Are they reporting the reaction constant of the reaction:

$HI + H_2O \implies  H_2I^+  + OH^- $

Is the $K_b$ for the equation?

That reaction seems so bizarre; it seems like the products are so unstable and reactive.

Comment: No, it's $K_\mathrm{b}$ of the conjugate base. The table header tells you this, although I guess it could be a bit more explicit: "Values of Ka, pKa, Kb, and pKb for Selected Acids HA  and Their Conjugate Bases (A−)".

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/24342/what-is-the-ka-of-oh-and-kb-of-h3o

Comment: Ah, I see. And the stronger the acid, the weaker the conjugate base. In this case, the conjugate base is $I^-$; however, it seems like it should have a good ability to accept a proton? Therefore, wouldn't it be a strong base?